# How to use python to run IOS Simulator

Tags: python, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to create a python script that I can use, to run the iOS simulator?

For example, I would use the python script to run the iOS simulator, run a specific app on the simulator, and go through the app and take screenshots.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should look into using Fastlane for taking screenshots of your application https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/TextEdit.app"]
    )
```

to open any app on your Mac see this post [How to open an application in Mac OS using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845242/how-to-open-an-application-in-mac-os-using-python)

You will probably have to go through your app by yourself. Have also a look at that post [Automate Screenshots on iPhone Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360552/automate-screenshots-on-iphone-simulator/1579182)

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of a way to mimic user touch’s with python? So I start the simulator, and now I want to open up “my app”, and I want to touch some buttons. I then take a screenshot. The use case for this, is I am remoting into my Mac, and I need to automatically take screenshots

Comment: Well of course you can mimic a mouse click see: [Controlling mouse with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python) but you have to configure that manually... And for the screenshot part you could trigger the hotkey that's available.

But all this will be pretty tedious...

Comment: Yes, that is amazing! This is exactly what I wanted! It is tedious, but I do screenshots for advertising every day manually. Making the script will make my life so much easier lol

Comment: Consider accepting my answer as correct if that's what you wanted. Thanks and happy coding.